# Is it possible to programmatically open share point library in explorer view using vbscript / vba? If yes, how?

Tags: windows, vba, vbscript

I can open IE object with VB script and navigate to the sharepoint URL and open it in the web view but I want to automate viewing the sharepoint library in the windows explorer view (as a list of folders) using the UNC path with VBscript/VBA and I am not sure how to approach it.

Comment: `CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "explorer.exe \\127.0.0.1"`

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't being too clear before, I want to open the sharepoint library in the windows explorer as view as a list of folders

Comment: Put your URL in instead.